# sticky header change color on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im wondering if you can help me here! Im working with a sticky header in JS and CSS. What I want is that when The header is on the top of the page it should be grey --> in scroll down it just disapier --> it appear again on scroll up but in black --> and when it reach the top of the page it becomes grey again... i couldnt make it by self so Im asking for a little help here... this is the whole code: 
So far I could do that the header is grey on top --> disapier on scroll down --> appear again on scroll up on black --> BUT COULDNT MAKE THAT IT CHANGE BACK to grey when scroll reach the top of the page.

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function () {
 if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
   }
}, 20);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down-b');
    }
}

if (st > lastScrollTop){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down-b').addClass('nav-up');
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

It works whith 4 css classes:

```
    header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
height: 55px;
background-color: #eee;
z-index: 3;
margin-bottom: 42px;
}

.nav-up {
top: -55px;
}
.nav-down {
top:0px; background-color: #eee;
}
.nav-down-b {
top:0px; background-color: #1c1a1b;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
    <header class="nav-down clearfix"> 

  <div class="container">
      <div class="pull-left logo-neg"><img src="/images/PW-emblem-neg.png"></div>
    <ul id="user-menu" class="pull-right">
      <li><a href="/customer-service"><img src="/images/Icon_Nav_Magnify.svg" alt="glass"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/customer-service"><img src="/images/Icon_Nav_Cart.svg" alt="cart"> </a></li>
      <li><a href="/customer-service"><img src="/images/Icon_Nav_Info.svg" alt="info"> </a></li>
      <li><a href="/customer-service"><img src="/images/Icon_Nav_Heart.svg" alt="favorits"> </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance everybody!!

Comment: You want the header to disappear when you scroll? And when you scroll back up it should be there, and be grey?

Comment: when you scroll up it sould be black but when it reach the top of the page should change to grey again (when the header is on the top sould always be grey and tourn black only on scroll up (on scroll down it just disapier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for everybody who needs an effect like i wanted to, id fix it... this is the javascript code working properly:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function () {
if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
}
}, 20);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down-b');
    }
}

if (st < delta){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down-b').addClass('nav-down');
}


lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

working with the html and css i writed above. :) Hope you find it usefull!

Comment: glade to help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this code it may help you

```js
    $(function () {

    // grab the initial top offset of the navigation
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

    // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
    var sticky_navigation = function () {
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

        // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'z-index': 10000000, 'background': 'black', 'color':'white', 'width':'100%' });
        } 
      
      
      else {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'background':'gray', 'width':'100%' });
        }
    };

    // run our function on load
    sticky_navigation();

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        sticky_navigation();
    });

    // NOT required:
    // for this demo disable all links that point to "#"
    $('a[href="#"]').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    });
```

```css
#demo_top_wrapper
{
  height:600px;
  }
#sticky_navigation
{
  background:gray;
  height:80px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo_top_wrapper">
        <div id="sticky_navigation_wrapper">
            <div id="sticky_navigation">
              this is sticky header
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It works nice :) but how can I do to make it disapier when scroll down? Im trying with:     if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { $('#sticky_navigation').addClass('nav-up') }           where nav-up = top: -55px; but it just make my header fixed to the top